# How does this Pseudocode for Insertion Sort Work?

Tags: pseudocode, insertion-sort

I'm taking a pseudocode class and I'm following the insertion sort algorithm just fine except for line 7. Could someone please explain what this means? The previous lines up to this point makes sense: line 6 means index/placeholder `A[i]` advances one step to the right. It's the next step I'm unclear on "i <- i - 1".

```
1 for j ← 2 to length[A]
2   do key ← A[j]
3     ▹ Insert A[j] into the sorted sequence A[1  j - 1].
4     i ← j - 1
5     while i > 0 and A[i] > key
6      do A[i + 1] ← A[i]
7         i ← i - 1
8     A[i + 1] ← key
```

Comment: It should mean "assign `i+1` to `i`". (I'm filing this under "why teaching with completely made up pseudocode is dumb".)

Answer (score 0):

while i is greater than 0, 
do some stuff,
then subtract one from i.
Otherwise, the loop will go on forever. (infinite loop)

Comment: Forty-Two, Thanks so much, this makes perfect sense - to exit the while loop and in turn brought the whole algorithm together for me.

Comment: Simple answer, but completely. I've got to be cautious it appears with some of the other responses I'm getting. - Will

Answer (score 0):

Actually, line 6 assigns the next cell's value to be the value of the current cell.  Line 7 shifts the index back by one.  In practical terms, say you reach this point in the loop:

```
(Assuming the first item is at index 1)
A = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
i = 4

Line 6: Set A[i+1] to have the value of A[i]
        ==> A[5]                        A[4]
        ==> A = { 1, 2, 3, *5*, 5, 6 }

Line 7: Shift i to the next lower position
        ==> i = 3
```

After this, the you've reached the end of the loop, and return to the top of the loop at line 5, where you test the loop's condition and continue.